# What does implode do in a pattern used for preg_replace_callback?

Tags: php, implode, preg-replace-callback

I am not a php dev and would like some help to understand

```
$keys = array_keys($parameters['macrons']);
        $pattern = '/([' . implode('', $keys) . '])ー/u';

        return preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches) use ($parameters) {
            return $parameters['macrons'][$matches[1]];
        }, $str);
```

There is also a yaml file looking like this:

```
- function: transliterateChoonpu
      parameters:
            macrons:
                a: ā
                i: ī
                u: ū
                e: ē
                o: ō
```

Comment: a symbol class like `[aiueo]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code look for some vowels followed by the ー([U+30FC Unicode character](https://unicode-table.com/en/30FC/)) in the string `$str` and replace them with their equivalent [chōonpu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C5%8Donpu) (**seems obvious regarding the function name**).

### Constructing the pattern

```
                       $keys = array_keys($parameters['macrons']);
```

`$parameters['macrons']` is an associative array:

```
array(
    'a' => 'ā',
    'i' => 'ī',
    'u' => 'ū',
    'e' => 'ē',
    'o' => 'ō'
)
```

The keys are referenced by `$keys`: `['a', 'i', 'u', 'e', 'o']`.

```
                   $pattern = '/([' . implode('', $keys) . '])ー/u';
```

[Imploding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the keys without separator allow to make the resulting pattern `'/([aiueo])ー/u'` which matches any vowel (except *y*) followed by the U+30FC Unicode character (called *Katakana-Hiragana Prolonged Sound Mark*) in a Unicode string.

### Replacing the vowels

```
       return preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches) use ($parameters) {
           return $parameters['macrons'][$matches[1]];
       }, $str);
```

For each matching vowel, [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) calls the anonymous function passed as the second parameter giving it the matched vowel. The result of this callback replaces the matched vowel in the resulting string (returned by *preg_replace_callback*).

The callback simply returns the value indexed by the matched vowel in the `$parameters['macrons']` associative array.

So, the vowels are replaced by their corresponding chōonpu !

Comment: What's the function of the "ー" that's before the /u ?  Thanks

Comment: I though it was a typo. But it's a [Unicode character to denote a prolonged sound](https://unicode-table.com/en/30FC/).

Comment: @Anne, Is this answering your question ?